# Origin of project.assets.json - file missing regularly

Tags: .net

I regularly get "'project.assets.json' not found" errors when we do merges, nuget package updates, etc.

It has become an almost daily annoyance.. not as irritating as nuget problems, but it's getting there.

What is the origin of that file, what purpose does it have? and what consumes it?

---

Here is an edit with more details:

I get regularly this error:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(167,5): error : Assets file 'D:\test\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7/win7-x64'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net47' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. You may also need to include 'win7-x64' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers.

Then when I look at the project dependencies, I see this:

[image: dependencies]

Even the other projects from the solutions don't seem to be found.

Visual studio really wants to make sure I have NET47 because if I have it only one time, it adds it a second time:

[image]

And the path makes no sense either:

[image]

but no bother trying to fix it, VS doesn't care what I type.. wonder why there is even a field here.

It feels like since the introduction of .NET Core everything has good weirdly inconsistent with an UI that just doesn't match how things are run in the background anymore.

The project is two .NET47 libs + 1 .NET core lib with the .NET47 framework.

This sight:

[image]

happens daily as the same lib is included in many different projects that all update it in some way.

also:

[image]

packages are installed, but they're not found at the same time.

Removing the packages and adding them back temporarily fixes the problem.

What could be causing this error?

Comment: It is used by .NET Core SDK to manage dependencies.

Comment: What would be the reason that it is regularly 'missing'? it's an error happening very regularly.

Comment: so you mix .NET Standard/Core project with other project types? Do you have scripts that remove `obj` folder? That file is in the folder and must be kept there.

Comment: @Lex, I have added a bunch of details in the main post; yes, the project is 2 .NET47 libs and an ASP Core one, but using .NET47 as well; we don't use the Core .Net framework itself at all.

Comment: We use Teamcity, so the source is regularly pulled and everything rebuilt from scratch, with no obj/bin folders in place.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like an issue with one or more `.csproj` file.

AFAIK `project.assets.json` is output of `dotnet restore`. This file is similar to `package-lock.json` from `npm`. The error you're seeing indicates that `dotnet restore` somehow failed to run or failed to find the correct package for your target framework.

Visual Studio's framework targeting UI isn't useful most of the time when you work across platforms, so I'd recommend getting to know SDK-style csproj format and use a separate text editor to hand edit it. It's way simpler than previous version of msbuild-style csproj.

I also recommend reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#how-to-specify-target-frameworks and see if your csproj somehow deviate from the expected values.

Comment: We don't do any cross platform: we target only Windows x64 (we're binding c++ libs compiled for x64). Also, I have rebuilt that project several times and re-imported all the source files, but the problem constantly remains the same.

Comment: so what you say means that if we do a project clean, and it wipes the content of the obj folder, then another restore is needed?

Comment: Yes, `dotnet restore` should be run before clean build. This should be optional per https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/23, so I'm not sure what's the issue here.

If you can give us a simplified repro (no code file, just the project and dependencies), maybe we can take a look at what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I had to remove the following line from the myproject.csproj file.

```
<BaseIntermediateOutputPath>mypath\obj\</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
```

apparently, some files of the intermediate build get copied to that folder, however other files are still placed in the default folder, no matter what the setting is. Removing that line places all files in the default folder and the build is not having that error anymore.